# I have a problem to scrape link with PhantomJS form this link

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs, headless-browser

## The Problem

I'm trying to take out the link of the video. The problem is that I need to perform a click on the video to generate the link, but ads apear and don't let me click on the video media player.

So, I need to understand where is the ads to click on them to make them disappear, or disabled them.

Thanks to the person who would like to help me.

PS : I need to use PhantomJS (Headless Browser) cause I don't want persons to install Chrome.

## Code

```
WebDriverManager.phantomjs().setup(); // WebDriver
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
    
driver.get("https://down-paradise.com/v/13k82cj8l-g68x4");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='playbox']")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


driver.get(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='metaframe rptss']")).getAttribute("src"));
    
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
                            
driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS was [discontinued](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344) by the author on March 8th, 2018. You should consider an alternative such as [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/), [GeckoDriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver), or [EdgeDriver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp) in headless mode.

If you are having issues with the web page crawling, you can run your browser with a browser window to double check everything is getting selected correctly. Once you are finished, you can run it headless.

EDIT:
After looking at the Github for PhantomJS, it would appear that the author has decided to begin working on PhantomJS 3. Perhaps the project is not closed after all.